# Sanitizing GET Request and result of scan

Tags: php, xss, sanitization

I am trying to sanitize my GET variables but Accuntrix is still complaining for some reason.

So I visit a page and the URL contains parameters.  I pass these parameters between pages.  To do this I do
something like the following

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="https://someDomain/someFolder/someFile.php?WT.var1=<?php echo $_GET['WT_var1']; ?>&var2=<?php echo $_GET['var2']; ?>&var3=<?php echo $_GET['var3']; ?>&var4=<?php echo $_GET['var4']; ?>" title="logo"><img src="logo.png"></a>
```

I have lots of links like this on the page, and when I first ran the page it was vunerable to cross site scripting because
I was not sanitizing the GET requests.  So at the top of the page, I put

```
<?php
    $_GET['WT_var1'] = htmlspecialchars($_GET['WT_var1']);
    $_GET['var2'] = htmlspecialchars($_GET['var2']);
    $_GET['var3'] = htmlspecialchars($_GET['var3']);
    $_GET['var4'] = htmlspecialchars($_GET['var4']);
?>
```

Initially, this seemed to work.  But I have recently run another scan, and every single link like the above shows up as a high.
The details look something like this

```
URL encoded GET input WT.var1 was set to 1}body{acu:Expre/**/SSion(prompt(926954))}
The input is reflected inside a text element.
```

And the exploit looks like this

```
/someFolder/someFile.php?WT.var1=1%7dbody%7bacu:Expre/**/SSion(prompt(941830))%7d&var2=&var3=&var4=
```

Is that not showing a sanitized url though?  Is this something I need to fix or is it a false/negative?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`htmlspecialchars()` encodes your variable for output as content in an html page. If you need to pass your variables through the url, you need [`urlencode(()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php).

So for example:

```
...someFolder/someFile.php?WT.var1=<?php echo urlencode($_GET['WT_var1']); ?>&var2...
```

Comment: Would I still keep the htmlspecialchars in place or remove this all together?  thanks

Comment: @kate_hudson You should remove it as a general cleaning rule and only use it when you echo text to the browser where it is part of the content of the page. Like content inside a paragraph tag for example.